# Find the limit points of $B = \{\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}: n=1,2,3, \cdots\}$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $B = \{\frac{(-1)^nn}{n+1}: n=1,2,3, \cdots\}$, find the limit
>    points of $B$.

I know that the limit points are $\{-1, 1\}$, however there are several questions I have:

1) Given any set, what are the strategies one looks for to find the limit points of that set? Is it generally "guess work"/intuition to find some candidates then using the definition of a limit point to prove that the "guessed" value is indeed a limit point?

2) I arrived at the answer of $\{-1, 1\}$ using the sequential definition of a limit point as follows: Let $b_n = (-1)^{n} [1-1/(n+1)]$ for $n \in \mathbf{N}$ and let $a_n = b_{2n-1}$. Then clearly $(a_n) \rightarrow -1$ and $a_n \neq -1$ for all $n$, so $-1$ is a limit point of $B$. Similarly, defining $c_n = b_{2n}$ shows that $1$ is a limit point of $B$. How can I prove $\{-1, 1\}$ are limit points of $B$ using the $\epsilon$-neighborhood definition of limit points? That is, a point $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if every $\epsilon$-neighborhood $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ of $x$ intersects the set $A$ in some point other than $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be simpler to see (though equivalent) if you just use the original formula $b_n=(-1)^n n/(n+1)$ and then define $a_n=b_{2n-1}=-(2n-1)/(2n)$ as you have done already. And with $c_n=b_{2n}=+2n/(2n+1)$ you get both the results you state, showing $-1,1$ are each limit points.